# Azure Mobile App ApiController and Database Access

Tags: .net, azure, azure-mobile-services

I have implemented an Azure Mobile App backend, and I have written an ApiController class. I can now successfully make requests to it and all is working fine. However, I want to store some data in a database at some point. If my class inherited from TableController, I knew how to do is because all the basic actions are defined there, however I cannot seem to find a valid way on how to store data to the database from an ApiController inherited class ?
Can anyone help ?

Thanks

T

Comment: inside your apicontroller methods you can make calls to the database and store whatever data you want. of course you have define the db schema and so on..

Comment: @Aravind can you point me to any docs on how to do so ? I didnt manage to get access to the db...

Comment: check this out. it talks about an existing db. you can always use it for a new db . https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/mobile-services/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-use-existing-sql-database.md

Comment: Ok so i tried this out , here is my code: `using (var context = new ApiContext()) {                     
                    context.UserDatas.Add(newData);
                    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }` I can see the database being correct in the Server Explorer, and I can add entries by SQL Code, but this one seems to fail no mattwer what I do ... any suggestion ?

Comment: check for any exceptions. debug the code and also see the logs..if nothing  there write logs wherever applicable. see if u have given proper firewall permissions to connect the db...

Comment: Well i can see the structure being created so the connection must work... I cant debug , if i remote connect the breakpoints dont hit somehow...

Comment: run the api on local so that you can debug and connect to sql azure .

Answer (score 1):

If you have a C#.NET Azure Mobile App backend, then it is generally set up with Entity Framework.  You can hook up your WebAPI to the same Entity Framework DbContext that the Mobile Apps section is using.